# Delete and recreate API in API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have a problem with API Manager 1.8.0 around the functionality of deleting an API and recreating it.

Let's say I've created the "file" API version 1.0.0 and after that I've deleted it and recreated it with the same name but version 1.0.1.

When I try accessing the "file/1.0.1" API I get a 404.
I know I could've done the version update for this but that's beside the point ( I believe so).
I've created a new API named "file1" with version 1.0.1 using the same parameters as for the "file" API above and "file1/1.0.1" works as expected.

I'm using an wso2 API Manager 1.8.0 as it comes OOTB no additional database or anything else.
Could you please advise how I could get the "file" API working again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete file API from publisher.
Go to /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default and delete the file API.
Then you will be able to create it again